# TypeError: Not All Arguments Converted during string formatting. calling the image object, What Am I Missing?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

New To Python And Tkinter.

A Simple Program To Display Selected BMP. PNG Images, working With Button.

TypeError:`Not All Arguments Converted during string formatting. calling the image object.`

What Am I Missing?

```
import os, sys
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog, Tkconstants 
from tkFileDialog   import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MyImage(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Example")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.askopenfile, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

    def askopenfile(self):
        filename= tkFileDialog.askopenfile(initialdir='C:/..',title='Select File' , filetypes=[('Bitmap Images', '*.bmp'),('Png Images', '*.png')])

        if filename == None:
            image = Image.open(filename)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        else:
            print("Cannot Open" % filename)
            return

    def show(self):
        image = photo
        image.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyImage().mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is the `filename` supposed to go in `"Cannot Open"`?! It would be nice to give us a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g. `'foo' % 'bar'`, in this case) and the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "not all arguments converted during string formatting" is caused by

```
"Cannot Open" % filename
```

which should presumably be something like

```
"Cannot open %r"%filename
```

Comment: Cannot Open. I think it is reading the filename as string; Is there a way to read as an image?